# Is there an equivalent to the BlockInput() Windows function for X11?

Tags: x11

In Windows, the [BlockInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instructs the OS to globally block mouse and keyboard input for all GUI applications, including other processes, not just the application's own process.

From the Windows docs about BlockInput():

> Blocks keyboard and mouse input events from reaching applications.
>   When input is blocked, real physical input from the mouse or keyboard
>   will not affect the input queue's synchronous key state (reported by
>   GetKeyState and GetKeyboardState), nor will it affect the asynchronous
>   key state (reported by GetAsyncKeyState). However, the thread that is
>   blocking input can affect both of these key states by calling
>   SendInput. No other thread can do this.

Is there any way that an application can block mouse and keyboard input from reaching other GUI applications in the same X-server session.

Comment: I don't think it is easily possible on Linux. Why do you want to do that? What is your motivation?

Comment: Also, are you asking about the desktop (ie. X11) or in a terminal (e.g. `ssh` without X11 forwarding, or console).?

Comment: I want to block input where my program is performing actions in background - I'm asking for terminal

Comment: On the desktop, if coding a GUI application, several toolkits (Qt, Gtk, Fox) have the ability to "disable" or "block" input widgets....

Comment: Why do you need to *block* input instead of simply ignoring it or discarding it?

Comment: I believe it is nearly impossible (Linux being free software, you could in theory change it to fit your needs, but that might take years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to launch a program with no input, you can do it from the shell like this:

`program </dev/null`

If you want to programmatically do the same thing then you need to open a handle to /dev/null yourself, fork() your program, use dup2() to reassign the input and output handles to the /dev/null handle, then exec() your child program.

Comment: I think the OP want to ignore *some* keyboard and mouse inputs *once* the program has started.... so redirecting like you propose does not answer the original question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Well, the OP doesn't say much more than he wants to block input. Needs more details if he wants a better answer.